# Passing parameter valued to number_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

The view code for passing a parameter to a number field

```
<%= f.number_field :cap, :value => params[:cap] %>
```

is not returning the parameter, as the HTML code attests

```
<input class=" number_field" id="azienda_cap" name="azienda[cap]" size="30" type="text" value="" />
```

However, for all other objects in the form (text_field, text_area, collection_select) the values are being populated from the URL

```
/aziendas/new?action=show&cap=20081&cognome=J&comune= ...
```

and debug on params does state

```
cap: "20081"
```

The API does not provide any particular clue here

Answer (score 0):

The value should be passed as the second argument of f.number_field, not as a key-value pair (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-number_field_tag for more info)

So, to resolve your issue, try changing your code in the view to:

`<%= f.number_field :cap, params[:cap] %>`

Comment: <%= f.number_field :cap, params[:cap] %> returns can't convert Symbol into Integer error.  I had that down first.  The I recalled that numbers are better handled in text_field.  Lo an behold <%= f.text_field :cap, :value => params[:cap] %> worked!  Thanks for the thought, it catalysed something...

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the variable is created as an integer, defining the form with a text_field instead adopts the param values.

```
<%= f.text_field :cap, :value => params[:cap] %>
```